# Get Response Header data from Post Call

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, post, microsoft-graph-api, httpresponse

I'm calling a Microsoft API to create a printer however I need a way to get the response header where the information about the post is.

I'm following this guide https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/printer-create?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=csharp but not sure how to extract the response from the call as I can not assign a variable to the call.

```
await graphClient.Print.Printers
    .Create(displayName,manufacturer,model,certificateSigningRequest,physicalDeviceId,hasPhysicalDevice,connectorId)
    .Request()
    .PostAsync();
```

> Operation-Location

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can send HTTP request with the .Net Microsoft Graph client library and read response headers.

Something like this:

```
var requestUrl = graphClient.Print.Printers.Request().RequestUrl;
var content = "json_content";
var hrm = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, requestUrl);
hrm.Content = new StringContent(content, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "aplication/json");
// Authenticate (add access token) 
await client.AuthenticationProvider.AuthenticateRequestAsync(hrm);
// Send the request and get the response.
var response = await client.HttpProvider.SendAsync(hrm);
if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    throw new ServiceException(
        new Error
        {
            Code = response.StatusCode.ToString(),
            Message = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()
        });
}     
else
{
    // read header values
    var headerValues = response.Headers.GetValues("Operation-Location");
}
```

Example of the request body:

```
{
  "displayName": "Test Printer",
  "manufacturer": "Test Printer Manufacturer",
  "model": "Test Printer Model",
  "physicalDeviceId": null,
  "hasPhysicalDevice": false,
  "certificateSigningRequest": { 
    "content": "{content}",
    "transportKey": "{sampleTransportKey}"
  },
  "connectorId": null
}
```

[Documentation](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet-core/blob/f11798e90dbb3dd3e16caeb500dba3fbc01da3fc/docs/overview.md#send-http-requests-with-the-net-microsoft-graph-client-library)