# How can I show Graph API post response in textbox?

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

In my C# custome Application I use the following code to create a one-on-one chat using user principal name.How can I show the following example response in the textbox of my c# application program.

```
    GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient( authProvider );
    var chat = new Chat
    {
    ChatType = ChatType.OneOnOne,
    Members = new ChatMembersCollectionPage()
    {
        new AadUserConversationMember
        {
            Roles = new List<String>()
            {
                "owner"
            },
            AdditionalData = new Dictionary<string, object>()
            {
                {"user@odata.bind", "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users('jacob@contoso.com')"}
            }
        },
        new AadUserConversationMember
        {
            Roles = new List<String>()
            {
                "owner"
            },
            AdditionalData = new Dictionary<string, object>()
            {
                {"user@odata.bind", "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users('alex@contoso.com')"}
            }
        }
    }
};

await graphClient.Chats
    .Request()
    .AddAsync(chat);
```

[image: Example Response]

[image: C# Custome Application]

[image: Error]

Comment: Do you want to save the response on textbox in teams application or any other custom application?

Comment: @Nivedipa-MSFT
I want to show the response header data in the textbox, this is my c# custom application. I have reffer the way of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66335358/get-response-header-data-from-post-call but I have face this error.

Answer (score 0):

First you can get the response of graph API in one variable.
And then add the value of that variable for textbox.

example:
var me = await graphClient.Me.Request().GetAsync();